# Draw a line inside WPF Dockpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I draw a line inside dockpanel? 
Here

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Play button. -->
            <Button Name="btnPlay"
                    Click="btnPlay_Click"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlayButton}"></Button>
            <!-- Pause button. -->
            <Button Name="btnPause"
                    Click="btnPause_Click"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PauseButton}"></Button>
        </Grid> How to draw a Red color line here with height eqals to content of dockpanel ?
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: You could set the Grids VerticalAlignment to Center, and the Stackpanels VerticalAlignment to Stretch, and then add a Border or Line on the marked position.

Comment: Where do you want your line? At the bottom of the DockPanel or around it or at the left of it (because you talk about height but not about width)?

Comment: Don't forget that if you want to overlay drawings (draw one over the other), you can easily do that with a grid by letting more than one control being in the same row/column.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a name of DockPanel or StackPanel inside it and add separator:

```
<Separator Width="{Binding ElementName=NameOfDockPanel, Path=ActualWidth}" 
           Background="Black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Separator is a good idea, or you could draw a simple rectangle in the dockpanel:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Play button. -->
            <Button Name="btnPlay"
                    Click="btnPlay_Click"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PlayButton}"></Button>
            <!-- Pause button. -->
            <Button Name="btnPause"
                    Click="btnPause_Click"
                    Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PauseButton}"></Button>
        </Grid>
        <Rectangle Width="5"
                   Fill="Red"
                   Margin="0" />
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just simply place your "Separator" into the DockPanel rather then inside one of the child item, they will Stack and the "Separator" will have the full height of the DockPanel.

```
 <DockPanel>

    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="Some other controls"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border Width="5"
            Background="Red"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
    <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Buttons and controls"/>

    </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a rectangle and dock it where you want... And fill it as per your requirement..

example

Answer (score 0):

Example for a line at the bottom:

```
<DockPanel Name="MyDockPanel"
           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Grid>
            <Button Name="btnPlay"
                    Click="btnPlay_Click"></Button>
            <Button Name="btnPause"
                    Click="btnPause_Click"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Line Stroke="Red"
          VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
          X1="0"
          X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MyDockPanel}"
          StrokeThickness="3"></Line>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for a line around your control (it could be around your dockPanel if you prefer, just put the border a level higher):

```
<DockPanel Name="MyDockPanel"
           DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
           VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Border  BorderBrush="Blue"
             BorderThickness="3">
        <!-- line around control -->
        <StackPanel  DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <Button Name="btnPlay"
                        Click="btnPlay_Click"></Button>
                <Button Name="btnPause"
                        Click="btnPause_Click"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DockPanel>
```